# add a Tag in an sorted array list

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

say i have a bunch of sorted  records (which is sorted multiple times) in my arrayList  e.g. :

```
Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 987
Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 934
Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 897
Country : USA  , State : Florida , Users : 745
Country : USA  , State : Florida , Users : 634
Country : USA  , State : Texas , Users : 564
```

as you can see the above data is sorted now i wanna add an tag (say an index) on this data so that it can look like this :

```
Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 987 , addedTag : 1 // ranked by same country and state
Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 934 , addedTag : 2 // ranked by same country and state
Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 897 , addedTag : 3 // ranked by same country and state
Country : USA  , State : Florida , Users : 745  , addedTag : 1 // rank from starting cause its a new state
Country : USA  , State : Florida , Users : 634 ,  addedTag : 2
Country : USA  , State : Texas , Users : 564 , addedTag : 1
```

any one knows how can i do it ??

Comment: you could create a new arraylist for each state, and append the user once you find them?

Comment: @return0 i have like 10000s of records and they are not like this , here i just  used state and country for ease to understand ,  so making individual arraylist can be not so efficient

Comment: If it is sorted, then start by using a counter, reset the counter every time you see a new state, and add it as a value to the current entry in the array list? Is that clear? would it work?

Comment: yeah this seem pretty good  , thanks man @return0 , let me try this

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously all a matter of iterating through the ArrayList and appending your desired tag with an incremental count where country and state are the same but yet resetting the count where country and state are not the same.

Below is a method conveniently named **addTag()** that will do this and if you have 10's of thousands of records to process then I would suggest running the code within a separate thread or executor service.

> **NOTE:** This method will modify the supplied ArrayList. If you want to keep the orginal ArrayList as it is then pass a clone to the
>   addTag() method supplied below.

Here is the method:

```
private void addTag(ArrayList<String> array) {
    int counter = 0;
    String country = "";
    String state = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        // Split the ArrayList comma delimited string element.
        String[] data = array.get(i).trim().split(",");
        String cntry = data[0].toLowerCase(); //hold the country for this element
        String stat = data[1].toLowerCase();  //hold the state for this element
        // start our tag appending
        if (i == 0) { 
            counter++;
            country = cntry;
            state = stat;
            array.set(i, array.get(i) + " , addtag : " + String.valueOf(counter));
        }
        else {
            // If we hit the same country and the same state again
            // then increment our counter and append tag to element.
            if (cntry.equalsIgnoreCase(country) && stat.equalsIgnoreCase(state)) {
                counter++;
                array.set(i, array.get(i) + " , addtag : " + String.valueOf(counter));
            }
            // If we don't hit the same country and the same state again
            // then reset the counter to 1 and append tag to element.
            else {
                country = cntry;
                state = stat;
                counter = 1;
                array.set(i, array.get(i) + " , addtag : " + String.valueOf(counter));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how you **might** use it:

```
// Example ArrayList...
ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
users.add("Country : CANADA  , State : Alberta , Users : 132");
users.add("Country : CANADA  , State : BC , Users : 232");
users.add("Country : CANADA  , State : BC , Users : 249");
users.add("Country : CANADA  , State : Ontario , Users : 888");
users.add("Country : CANADA  , State : Ontario , Users : 432");
users.add("Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 987");
users.add("Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 934");
users.add("Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 897");
users.add("Country : USA  , State : Florida , Users : 745");
users.add("Country : USA  , State : Florida , Users : 634");
users.add("Country : USA  , State : Texas , Users : 564");

// Before using the addtag() method...
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(users.get(i));
}
System.out.println("\n===================================="
        + "==========================\n");

// The supplied ArrayList MUST be sorted
// before passing it to this method.
addTag(users);

// After using the addtag() method...
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(users.get(i));
}
```

And here is the example console output:

```
Country : CANADA  , State : Alberta , Users : 132
Country : CANADA  , State : BC , Users : 232
Country : CANADA  , State : BC , Users : 249
Country : CANADA  , State : Ontario , Users : 888
Country : CANADA  , State : Ontario , Users : 432
Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 987
Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 934
Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 897
Country : USA  , State : Florida , Users : 745
Country : USA  , State : Florida , Users : 634
Country : USA  , State : Texas , Users : 564

======================================================

Country : CANADA  , State : Alberta , Users : 132 , addtag : 1
Country : CANADA  , State : BC , Users : 232 , addtag : 1
Country : CANADA  , State : BC , Users : 249 , addtag : 2
Country : CANADA  , State : Ontario , Users : 888 , addtag : 1
Country : CANADA  , State : Ontario , Users : 432 , addtag : 2
Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 987 , addtag : 1
Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 934 , addtag : 2
Country : USA  , State : California , Users : 897 , addtag : 3
Country : USA  , State : Florida , Users : 745 , addtag : 1
Country : USA  , State : Florida , Users : 634 , addtag : 2
Country : USA  , State : Texas , Users : 564 , addtag : 1
```